# Tipping for takeout food in the USA

Tags: usa, restaurants, tipping

When I go to a restaurant in the USA and order food for takeout, am I supposed to tip?

Comment: I am sorry about deleting my answer, but really, I did not intend to create such disagreement. **I** tip carry out, perhaps I should not, but I do. I make a good living and tend to overtip, but that is just me.

Comment: @CGCambell, I would encourage you ro undelete your answer. The beauty of SE is that users can still see alternate perspectives, with the best floating to the top. While many may not think yours was the best, it was still valid.

Comment: Something to note that may have caused this question in the first place is that often places where you carry out your food will use the same machine to print the receipt as they would for a delivery. The receipt will have a line for a tip amount, but that's more for the delivery driver.

Comment: No, I don't tip when I pick up the food myself or have it handed across the counter to me. Tips are to pay the server for their personal attention and service. Counter staff should be getting paid at least minimum wage (which still sucks a lot, but there's limits to everything). Unless I'm getting personal attention and service, food and drinks brought out to me, etc, I don't tip.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No. You don't tip unless it's a delivery charge. For example, if you order takeout food and have them deliver (especially common in hotels), then you'd want to tip the driver.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratuity#United_States):

> Tips are also generally given for services provided in golf courses,
>   casino, hotels, concierge, **food delivery**, taxis, spa and salons.

If you're going to the restaraunt or venue to pick up food, then you don't need to leave a tip.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratuity#United_States):

> Tipping is not required for fast food restaurants, **take-out orders**,
>   and coffee houses.

Comment: You say "obviously" but tipping isn't expected in a lot of countries for that kind of thing either.

Comment: @CMaster The question title specifically states: "Tipping for takeout food in **USA**". So the OP is not asking what the standard is in other countries.

Comment: @thinly_veiled_question_mark You misunderstand what I was trying to say. You say it is "obvious" to tip the driver in the USA - but the reason there are so many questions about tipping on this site is because tipping varies dramatically between cultures - what may be obvious to a native is often surprising to a traveller. I'm not disputing the accuracy or relevance of the answer.

Comment: @Cmaster As I am aware of that, but in the US you generally tip if it's a delivery service for food, which is something I've added as an edit.

Comment: so you don't believe in tipping huh? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-qV9wVGb38

Comment: What do you mean by "(especially common in hotels)"? I'm pretty sure people order Chinese food at home too. This is bugging me way more than it should.

Comment: @Paul Sorry; I meant it as a reference to the service; not the particular choice of food. When you go to most hotels they often have flyers for local restaraunts that serve delivery; whether it be Italian, Chinese, American, or any other cuisine.

Comment: Takeout delivered to a hotel? Wouldn't that go under concierge or room-service, neither which you tip (as it's added to your room bill)

Comment: @ClausJørgensen no, you can get food delivered to your hotel from a restaurant which is not affiliated with the hotel, even if the hotel offers room service.

Comment: @Andy Sure, but that's what concierge is for. Maybe in less posh hotels this is more common, but I still find it a rather strange example.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen even at fancy hotels sometimes I want a pizza, and with the internet I can easily find one myself.  Even if a concierge recommended one its unlikely they'd order it for me.  I think this is more common than you believe.

Comment: This answer is a bit confusing.  You tip if the food is delivered, whether you pay a delivery charge or not.

Answer (score 18):

No, I wouldn't.  A tip is for good service (someone bringing food drink to your table, keeping on top of your requests etc.) but with takeout you're buying a product.  Its similar to going to McDonalds or Wendy's.

Generally, its waiters and waitresses that get tips as they make a lower Federal minimum wage than the other staff.  While some states have laws which force employers to at least pay the standard minimum wage if the worker doesn't earn enough tips, most don't.

Also you usually would tip someone that delivers your food to you, but that's not relevant for takeout.

Here's some useful information from the US Dept of Labor.  http://www.dol.gov/whd/state/tipped.htm

I also found this good Trip Advisor article. http://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g191-s606/United-States%3aTipping.And.Etiquette.html

My experience comes from living in the US.

Comment: so then why do you have to tip in a bar for drinks? The process is the same as McDonalds etc. You go to the counter, order your drink then go sit down. I dont understand why it is required to tip in the bar situation but not in a Fast Food situation.

Comment: @davidb According to one of the links I posted, the FSLA states that you are a "tipped employee" if more than $30 of income is normally generated from tips in a single month.  Given that, it seems that bartenders could technically be paid a minimum wage of $2.13/hr. just like your server.  Also, while YOU might order a drink and leave, people do sit at the bar and the bartender takes care of anything else they might want as well, such as snacks, appetizers or even full meals.  In fact my wife and I often have our entire meal at the bar b/c the service is better than at a table.

Comment: @davidb The bartenders remember who tips and who doesn't.  I can tell you from personal experience (I live in the USA) that if you make a habit of tipping bartenders, you will get service much quicker than if you do not.  At a busy bar, the bartenders decide who gets served and in what order.  Why would they choose to serve someone who they know doesn't tip over someone who does?

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff Plus your drink might be more waterer down than someone that tips well (or perhaps their drink gets an extra kick).

Comment: @Andy Very true.  :)

Answer (score 15):

The people at the takeout counter probably aren't dependent largely on tips as their primary wage (as waitstaff in the US *are*), but if your order is complicated, it is courteous to tip. And, I'd recommend being consistent with a dollar or two if this is a neighborhood restaurant you order from frequently — they'll remember.

The blog "Wait But Why" has a long [article on tipping](http://waitbutwhy.com/2014/04/everything-dont-know-tipping.html), based on extensive but non-scientific research. It's worth reading in general, but to summarize the relevant part for *this* question:

- About a third of take-out customers tip
- If you don't tip, it's fine
- Average tip is "$0-1"
- High tip is 10-20%
- And, the blog notes: "if you order for 10 people and it's all carefully packaged, that took time. Tip."

Comment: Last point is fair enough I suppose.

Comment: At many restaurants, the takeout counter is at the bar.  I believe that bartenders **are** dependent largely on tips.

Comment: @pacoverflow True, but irrelevant.  They hand you the food and ring you out, and that's about it.

Comment: @Andy You could say the same about them handing you your drink and ringing you out.

Comment: @pacoverflow And if you're only going to get one drink, not tipping wouldn't be that big a deal, although I would if I were waiting for the takeout.  And you wouldn't typically tip for a soft drink as well, given by the very same bartender, no matter how long you sat there.  At any rate, having the bartender hand you the food and take your money isn't a service you tip for.  Its not like they packed it or even brought it to the bar.

Answer (score 12):

Generally the worker at the cashier will take tips if given, but they aren't required. Usually the "tip jar" in those circumstances serves as a "put that pocket change you didn't actually want here," like if you're paying cash or the like.

Just because there is a jar of some sort next to the cash register doesn't mean they take tips, either; Some establishments collect customers' spare change to make charitable contributions to various organizations (one notable example is McDonald's and their partnership with the Ronald McDonald House).  These are completely optional, and the money does not go to anyone at the restaurant.  This practice is also the exception, rather than the rule.

Basically, if a place has a tip jar at the point of payment, and you pay in cash, it's generally appreciated for you to put some or all of the change into the jar, but it is never required.

Comment: But there's the issue. If you see a jar for money going to an organization, that's not a tip; that's a donation.  A tip is intended to go towards the staff of the restaurant; a donation goes towards a charitable organization. So in my opinion I'd omit the second paragraph, as it has nothing to do with a "tip jar", which is often labelled as such.

Comment: @thinlyveiledquestionmark Good point, I'll rewrite it as appropriate. (I still think it's worth mention as an ancillary thing though.)

Answer (score 6):

I've worked in a bunch of restaurants (many years ago) as both a waitress and a bartender. In both instances I've placed takeout orders for customers either in the restaurant or calling in to pick up. At the time I was making below the standard minimum wage because it's assumed by the government that I'll make it up in tips. That was not always the case.

When a waitress or bartender "cashes out" at the end of the night, they print out how much they "sold" and have to tip out other people at the restaurant that don't get tips (ie. bus boys, kitchen staff, hostess, bartender, it really depends on the establishment). Now the amount that they have to tip out to these co-workers varies but it's been as high as 5% of the sales. So if most people tip 15%, 5% of that goes to the other staff and the waitress / bartender makes 10% for themselves. That's IF they're getting 15% on average, which is not always the case.

Now take into account a take out order...If I take the order, I have to put that under my "sales" for the night and have to tip out the other staff on the sales. It was always appreciated when someone would tip on their takeout order so that I wouldn't lose money on it.

That's how it worked in the restaurants and bars that I worked in. I'm not saying that's how it is everywhere, but that's how I've always know it to be and that's why I tip on take out orders (from restaurants or bars).

Comment: I don't think what you make is relevant to tipping, it has to do with the service you're providing.  Its meant to encourage good service, but if you're just handing me food and taking my money that's not service.  I can see how that scenario would suck for a waitress, but there are a lot of things that suck about various jobs and its between employer and employee, not the customer.

Comment: For better or worse, it is generally illegal for "tip pools" to include normally non-tipped workers like those in the back of the house (kitchen staff). Other laws vary by state. Where I am in Massachusetts, many states now include a separate, technically-optional (in that you can ask a manager to remove it, if you are an asshole) "service fee" of 3-5% which goes to those non-tipped workers.

Answer (score 0):

The server usually packages and bags the meal, as well as checks you out. This is time they could be earning tips at the table. I always tip at least a couple of dollars. However, fast food restaurants are jumping on the bandwagon with a push for tips. I do not tip at fast food restaurants.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please do not type in all-capitals; it is considered SHOUTING, and besides is more difficult to read than standard mixed case text. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.